# Display SQL Server table values using jdbc

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Below is my code to display SQL Server values using jdbc. I have a problem. it says it is connected, but cannot display the values from the table specified. it says, invalid object name .

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DateServer{
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
String user = "abc";
String pass = "def";

Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
Connection con =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname:port;database name>, user, pass);

System.out.println("connected");

Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT CommentID FROM Comment");
while (res.next()) {
  int i = res.getInt("CommentID");
  System.out.println(i);
}
con.close();
}
}
```

Below is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid     object name 'Comment'.
at   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:775)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:611)
at DateServer.main(DateServer.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Comment` is a reserved word, therefor you need to quote it in the select statement:

```
 st.executeQuery("SELECT CommentID FROM \"Comment\"");
```

Comment: @ghbhatt: are you sure you do have such a table? What happens if you run that statement in the SQL tool of your choice?

Comment: When i run it using Visual Studio, I am able to see the values. But when I try to access it using JDBC, it gives me invalid object name.

Comment: @ghbhatt: and you are sure, you are connecting to the **same** database in both cases?

Comment: are any other tables via jdbc working? Is your connection url correct?

Comment: is there a way i can check if i am connected to the database or not? i do not want to retrieve values (for now), i just want to check if it is connected.